# CookieHeaderValue could not be found

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# Class library and for some reason I Am getting the following error:

The type or namespace 'CookieHeaderValue' could not be found.

I have

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

And the library is in my refernces.  I am targeting .NET 4.5.2

Comment: Try delete reference and add it again. This method helped me several times.

Comment: @Krzyserious That did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.

Just right-click on references -> Add references -> Extensions -> System.Net.Http.Formatting

Comment: I had to add the library through nuget as it was not listed where you mentioned but it was definitely what i needed. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/